# How to connect a separate webpage opened from a shortcut to a main web app? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, window, shortcut

I'm opening up a specific page from my web app via a shortcut (a url the user saves and can send/email). When the user opens the shortcut, I need to connect the  opened window to the main web app if they have it open. I can check a cookie to see if the main web app is up, but I'm not sure how to actually establish a link between the two windows without redirecting/closing the new window. Im using .NET framework 4.7.x

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "connect the opened window to the main web app if they have it open"? It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The web app acts like a single page application, and frequently opens other windows that it then communicates with in order to properly update information, store info in the database, etc. So when this new shortcut window is opened I need to somehow establish that connection again so that the proper communication can occur. The new window needs to be able to access the main web page